# Suggestion on web application performance test

Tags: performance, testing, performance-testing

I am planning to start a performance test against a web application. This application employs Ajax UI, SQL Server database backend, and a WCF business logic layer. So far, no performance has been done for it. And we don't have a performance requirement yet. But we have released for several times. So I am planning to make a performance baseline based on a major release. I got the following questions:

- How would the baseline look like? i.e. What is a baseline made of?
- What kind of tools could I use to generate the conent to be included in the baseline? ( Microsoft product will be better.)

Any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Whose performance do you want to test?

Comment: the web application as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do

1) You can use the qtp or any other tools your company is doing to get the details of your page.
2) There are some third party company's like keynote etc which can tell you about the performance.
3) use pagespeed, yslow tools also to get the details from the browser point.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to the performance, I think let's start from the beginning...

As for a web application performance testing, first of all, and very roughly to speak we need to separate into two sides: back-end and front-end performance testing.

So, the reason is simple, even we got yslow,pagespeed,dynatace's result saying that the total page loading time is around *10s*, we can not knowing where the problem is and how to solve it. Cause:

- Both front-end and server side will be the bottle neck.
- Most front end tools are *single thread*, we can't know under how concurrent loads env how bad will happen.
- Even the code in the server side is very fast, we also need to tune the front end side

Here is some tools for the back-end and front-end performance testing:

***Back-end***

1. Jmeter/Grinder: both are opening source library, I prefer grinder better.
2. htmlunit: the library is pure java and simulate concurrent loads to the server side. Also, selenium's htmlunit driver is another choice.
3. [browsermob](http://browsermob.com/website-load-testing) is another choice.

***Front-end***

I can list more but most common useful is "YSLOW","pagespeed","dynatrace","httpwatch"